# How to call custom hook conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got this `useTimeout` custom hook where I want it to run only when `on` is true. Right now I get this error: " React Hook "useTimeout" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. " I also get another error message: " Cannot find name 'handleMouseEnter'. " , since custom hook is wrapped inside of useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) return; const { handleMouseEnter, handleMouseLeave } = useTimeout(onCloseButtonClick, autoDismissDuration); }, 
[open]);}

<div onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}></div>
```

So to solve this, I tried passing `on` state to custom hook as parameter like this

```
const useTimeout = (open, onCloseButtonClick, autoDismissDuration) => { 
  if(open) ...run the logic
```

But how can I call `useTimeout` hook whenever `open` value changes? Tried putting this inside of `useEffect` hook with open dependency, but that's considered illegal.

Comment: _"How to call custom hook conditionally?"_ you can't. https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a hook conditionally, but you can:

1. Write your own custom hook that has the logic you want, or:
2. Conditionally render another component that has the `useTimeout` hook.